# Creating a pivot table with certain criteria in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

When using my macro, the pivot table that already exists does not completely match the other sheet's information, so I am clearing out the pivot table sheet "TJC" and entering a new one from another sheet "TJ". I used a macro recorder to show exactly what I want in the pivot table. I am not sure how to get certain criteria for the table, but if you need more information besides this macro recorder, let me know.

```
isum.Sheets("TJ").Cells.Select
Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("H13").Select
Sheets("TJC").Select
Cells.Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "TJCust!R1C1:R1048576C7", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="TJCust!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("TJCust").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .ColumnGrand = True
    .HasAutoFormat = True
    .DisplayErrorString = False
    .DisplayNullString = True
    .EnableDrilldown = True
    .ErrorString = ""
    .MergeLabels = False
    .NullString = ""
    .PageFieldOrder = 2
    .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RowGrand = True
    .SaveData = True
    .PrintTitles = False
    .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
    .TotalsAnnotation = False
    .CompactRowIndent = 1
    .InGridDropZones = False
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
    .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
    .DisplayContextTooltips = True
    .ShowDrillIndicators = True
    .PrintDrillIndicators = False
    .AllowMultipleFilters = False
    .SortUsingCustomLists = True
    .FieldListSortAscending = False
    .ShowValuesRow = False
    .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
    .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
Range("B10").Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Item$SV$Item")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Hand_Amount"), _
    "Count of Hand_Amount", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "Count of Hand_Amount")
    .Caption = "Sum of Hand_Amount"
    .Function = xlSum
End With
```

Comment: I will try and post some code for you to look at, regarding criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code below a pivot table is created and named.
The xlRowFields are your categories (and sub categories).
The xlDataFields are your column data (and type of function on that data) for your categories.  Then the Pivot table is sorted based on Column (DataField) values.

There is quite a bit of code exempted from this example, for instance there are new columns built finding averages for each pivot row, and a copy into pretty much a data table for easier formatting of the entire table before it is copied into a report (as a cell based table, not as a pivot any longer)

```
Option Explicit

'Added this code so you can see where the worksheet is coming from
'Use your own worksheet set up here
Dim CalcSheet as Worksheet
Set CalcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc Sheet")

'***************************************
'Make the Sales-Customer Pivot and table
'***************************************

    '***************************
    'Add Sales Pivot Table
    'Also edited to place the Picot in cell A1 of the worksheet that you set up above
    'Do not forget to modify the SourceData Range for your intended data range . . . 
    'Walk through this line by line so you understand what is happening

   ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        CalcSheet.Range("K14:AY" & LastDR), Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=CalcSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="SalesPVT", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Salesperson")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Customer")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("DD Rev")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    End With

    With CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Job Days")
        .Orientation = xlDataField
        .Function = xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With

    CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").PivotFields("Salesperson").AutoSort _
        xlDescending, "Sum of DD Rev"
```

Here is how the Pivot table can be copied, dealing with them on reports is not that much fun when building further calculation columns off the data.

```
'copy pivot table to get rid of it
 CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").TableRange1.Copy
'Paste it as values with formatting
CalcSheet.Range("CA100").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

This is deleting the pivot table that was created after copy

```
 CalcSheet.PivotTables("SalesPVT").TableRange1.Delete
```

Comment: How would I make the pivot table on an existing sheet (for example Sheet5) on cell A1? Instead of copying and pasting

Comment: Modify this part: TableDestination:=CalcSheet.Range("CA37"), you will have to walk through the code and change it for your purposes, this pivot example is being used on CalcSheet, you will have to change a number of parameters based on your workbook and your data.